# How to call a PHP function from a HTML button click?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Can someone help me with some javascript that will allow me to call a function when I click on a button?

I know this has been posted before, but every answer I have seen is too vague and I have been at this for 8 hours now :(

Please bear in mind I am a javascript beginner.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
    <table border cellpadding=5>
        <div>
            <tr>
                <th>Report</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Students with highest scores</td>
                <td>
                    <button type= button>Generate report</button>
                </td>

        </div>
    </table>
    <?php   

        function highestScore()
        {
            $data = mysql_query("SELECT t.Test_name, s.Student_firstname, s.Student_surname, sc.Result
                                 FROM Tests t 
                                 JOIN Scores sc ON t.id_Tests = sc.Tests_id_Tests
                                 JOIN Students s ON sc.Students_id_Students = s.id_Students
                                 WHERE t.id_Tests = 1
                                 ORDER BY sc.Result DESC");
                    if(!$data)
                    {
                        die("Invalid Query: " . mysql_error());
                    }
            Print"<table border cellpadding=5>";
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
            {
            Print"<tr>";
            Print "<th>Test:</th> <td>" . $info['Test_name'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>First Name:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_firstname'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Surname:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_surname'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Result:</th> <td>" . $info['Result'] . "</td> ";
            }
            Print "</table>";
        }

    ?>
</body>
```

I want to use the "Generate report" button I have made, to execute the "highestScore" function.

The function creates a table of values from a mySQL database.

There will eventually be more buttons which bring up different tables.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to communicate with the server using AJAX.

Comment: PHP code is executed on the server and javascript code in the browser. You CAN'T execute php from javascript. But you can communicate through AJAX call.

Comment: If you're starting out I wouldn't go straight to AJAX. Learn about how browsers interact with servers via Request and Response. Then learn about the HTML `<form>` tag and its' `post` and `get` variations and how they work with PHP. Once you have a little more experience with PHP on the server and javascript on the client, then look at technologies like AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

`HTML` and `Javascript` run on the browser while `PHP` runs on the server. You will have to make another server call either by using `AJAX` or refreshing the page. Here's how to do it with `AJAX` without refreshing the page. ([$.ajax docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

1. Create a new `PHP` page: `query.php` with the following code:

   ```
   <?php   

           $data = mysql_query("SELECT t.Test_name, s.Student_firstname, s.Student_surname, sc.Result
                                FROM Tests t 
                                JOIN Scores sc ON t.id_Tests = sc.Tests_id_Tests
                                JOIN Students s ON sc.Students_id_Students = s.id_Students
                                WHERE t.id_Tests = 1
                                ORDER BY sc.Result DESC");
                   if(!$data)
                   {
                       die("Invalid Query: " . mysql_error());
                   }
           Print"<table border cellpadding=5>";
           while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
           {
           Print"<tr>";
           Print "<th>Test:</th> <td>" . $info['Test_name'] . "</td> ";
           Print "<th>First Name:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_firstname'] . "</td> ";
           Print "<th>Surname:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_surname'] . "</td> ";
           Print "<th>Result:</th> <td>" . $info['Result'] . "</td> ";
           }
           Print "</table>";

   ?>
   ```
2. Use the button's click event to run an ajax request: (Add the following script to your `HTML` page)

   ```
   $(function(){
       $('button').click(function(){
           $.ajax({
               url:'query.php',
               success:function(response){ alert(response); }
           }); // this will alert the code generated in example.php
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using button, use a form with a submit button. Send a request by POST, and detect that in PHP using isset($_POST['report']) and then display your report.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
    <table border cellpadding=5>
        <div>
            <tr>
                <th>Report</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Students with highest scores</td>
                <td>
            <form method="POST">
                            <input type="submit" name="report">Generate report</button>
            </form>
                </td>

        </div>
    </table>
    <?php   

        function highestScore()
        {
            $data = mysql_query("SELECT t.Test_name, s.Student_firstname, s.Student_surname, sc.Result
                                 FROM Tests t 
                                 JOIN Scores sc ON t.id_Tests = sc.Tests_id_Tests
                                 JOIN Students s ON sc.Students_id_Students = s.id_Students
                                 WHERE t.id_Tests = 1
                                 ORDER BY sc.Result DESC");
                    if(!$data)
                    {
                        die("Invalid Query: " . mysql_error());
                    }
            Print"<table border cellpadding=5>";
            while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
            {
            Print"<tr>";
            Print "<th>Test:</th> <td>" . $info['Test_name'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>First Name:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_firstname'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Surname:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_surname'] . "</td> ";
            Print "<th>Result:</th> <td>" . $info['Result'] . "</td> ";
            }
            Print "</table>";
        }

    if (isset($_POST['report'])) {
        highestScore();
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

A raw button doesn't make sense in pure HTML. It **does just nothing** - except looking like a button.

You may use it **in conjunction with JavaScript**:

```
<form action="input_button.htm">

    <textarea cols="20" rows="4" name="field1"></textarea>

    <input type="button" name="Text 1" value="Add some new Text"
      onclick="this.form. field1.value='Some new Text'">

</form>
```

This button executes a JavaScript through a click on it - and replaces the `textarea` named `field1`.

Answer (score 0):

So you want this all on one page so the first thing you need is `form` html tag wrapped around the button, I have named mine 'submit' and set the action to the page itself `<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>`. When the button is clicked it will preform your php code

Script

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<table border cellpadding=5>
    <div>
        <tr>
            <th>Report</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Students with highest scores</td>
            <td>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"> <!-- Calls for the PHP script on the page-->
                <button type= button>Generate report</button>
                </form>
            </td>

    </div>
</table>
<?php  
    //Script that is called

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //The ID of the form we used is 'submit' so when that is clicked it will execute this
    function highestScore()
    {
        $data = mysql_query("SELECT t.Test_name, s.Student_firstname, s.Student_surname, sc.Result
                             FROM Tests t 
                             JOIN Scores sc ON t.id_Tests = sc.Tests_id_Tests
                             JOIN Students s ON sc.Students_id_Students = s.id_Students
                             WHERE t.id_Tests = 1
                             ORDER BY sc.Result DESC");
                if(!$data)
                {
                    die("Invalid Query: " . mysql_error());
                }
        Print"<table border cellpadding=5>";
        while($info = mysql_fetch_array($data))
        {
        Print"<tr>";
        Print "<th>Test:</th> <td>" . $info['Test_name'] . "</td> ";
        Print "<th>First Name:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_firstname'] . "</td> ";
        Print "<th>Surname:</th> <td>" . $info['Student_surname'] . "</td> ";
        Print "<th>Result:</th> <td>" . $info['Result'] . "</td> ";
        }
        Print "</table>";
    }


    highestScore(); //executes your function you created
    }

?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript run on the browser while PHP runs on the server. You have to write Ajax or java-script.In java-script you can call the php page and do your stuff in that page.And it would be the better approach.You can pass the variable also.I post a example here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function removeItem(oButton) 
{
var hello = "hello";
var world = "world";
window.location.href = "trytest.php?w1=" + hello + "&w2=" + world;//Your page location
}       
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h2>This is the test </h2>
<button type="show" onclick="removeItem(this); return false;">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```